# phpmyadmin split string in column by delimiter to open columns to the right

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have extremely limited knowledge regarding MySQL, PHPMyAdmin, etc. as a whole, I am learning as I go.

**Background**

A QR code is scanned, and the string inside the `QR code = a12345,test,01/01/2021,tes2`.

This string is then added to the MySQL database.

**Question**

How do I split the sting by delimiter in PHPMyAdmin?

Please see the example below.

*Current:*

| id | QRscan | number | name | date | name2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1. | a12345,test,01/01/2021,tes2 |  |  |  |  |

*Final:*

| id | QRscan | number | name | date | name2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1. | a12345,test,01/01/2021,tes2 | a12345 | test | 01/01/2021 | tes2 |

Comment: If it is always in the same format `number, name, date, name2`, you can use the `SUBSTRING_INDEX` function.

Comment: yes it is always in the same format.

Comment: You should store the date as a date datatype in the form yyyy-mm-dd. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-types.html  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [substring_index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) function as the following:

```
select substring_index(QRscan, ',', 1) number,
       substring_index(substring_index(QRscan, ',', 2), ',', -1) name,
       substring_index(substring_index(QRscan, ',', 3), ',', -1) date_,
       substring_index(QRscan, ',', -1) name2
from tbl_name
```

And to update your table:

```
update tbl_name
set number = substring_index(QRscan, ',', 1),
    name = substring_index(substring_index(QRscan, ',', 2), ',', -1),
    date_ = str_to_date(substring_index(substring_index(QRscan, ',', 3), ',', -1), '%d/%m/%Y'),
    name2 = substring_index(QRscan, ',', -1)
-- where some condition, i.e. id = 1, number is null... etc
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/FDComLtf)